# LESS css: error evaluating function `floor`: argument must be a number

Tags: javascript, css, less

I am trying to calculate the floor of a LESS calculation like so:

```
@small_width: calc(~'24vw - 6px');
@floor_small_width: floor(@small_width);
```

but keep getting this error:

```
error evaluating function `floor`: argument must be a number
```

From my understanding **@small_width** isn't calculated until runtime so it will never be a number until runtime. Is there a workaround for this where I can get the floor of a computed value based a calculation at runtime?

**To add more color to my problem:**

I have two photo sizes based on the viewport:

```
            &.small{
                width: calc(~'24vw - 6px');
                height: calc(~'24vw - 6px');
            } // &.small
            &.large{
                width: calc(~'48vw - 6px');
                height: calc(~'48vw - 6px');
            } // &.large
```

I need 4 small photos to fit into 1 big photo. the problem is with decimal precision and the viewport. Depending on the viewport 4 small photos do not fit in exactly one big photo.

I want to get the floor of the small photo so I can base the big photo calculation off the size of the small photo.

Comment: What would you need this for? Browsers are capable of rounding themselves wherever necessary. If you want any element to be as wide as 24 percent of the viewport width minus six pixels is - then you can just put `calc(~'24vw - 6px')` _there_, so what you would need this floor-ed value in a variable for, is apart from the technical impossibility, really unclear. Please go read [ask], and describe what the actual problem you are trying to solve here is.

Comment: `@small_photo_width` is not defined in your example.

Comment: @CBroe I have added the exact context to my problem

Comment: You don't need calc in your new example.

Comment: @Sonx I've updated my answer. This isn't an issue of decimal precision. It's most likely being caused by padding or borders contributing to the width of the element.

Comment: I don't think the problem is so much with precision, as with your math and/or your approach to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't store a `calc()` result in a variable because `calc()` is evaluated at runtime by the browser, while the variable is evaluated by LESS in the pre-compilation stage. The two don't know anything about each other.

Instead, you need to put the `calc()` operation on every attribute that uses it and you cannot use LESS math functions on it. That said, you shouldn't need to worry about flooring a value since browsers can handle the floating point numbers just fine.

```
.something {
  width: calc(24vw - 6px);
  height: calc(24vw - 6px);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Viewport units and the browser decimal precision should never cause wrapping. What's most likely happening is you've got padding or a border set on the items. In order to make padding and borders not contribute to the overall width of the element, you need to set the `box-sizing` attribute to `border-box`.

```
.small {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense - I have added more information to my exact problem in hopes to find a work around.

Comment: @Sonx see my update for an explanation of why you might be getting wrapping.

Comment: when getting the width's via jQuery after the page is loaded I am getting:

$('.small').css('width');
"227px"
$('.large').css('width');
"453px"

which is 1 pixel off (even with box-sizing: border-box;)

Comment: That's because jQuery is rounding the values. Just let the browser do it's thing.

Comment: Either that, or you have a border around your large image and that's causing it to subtract 1 pixel from the entire width.

Comment: Correction: you [*can*](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40var%3A%20calc(24vw%20~'-'%206px)%3B%5Cn%5Cn.something%20%7B%5Cn%20%20width%3A%20%40var%3B%5Cn%20%20height%3A%20%40var%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D) store `calc` expression in a variable. It's just can't be used with any Less function as it won't become a number until the thing gets to a browser.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I meant you can't store the _result_ of the calc in a less variable, only the literal calc statement. I'll update my answer to clarify this.

Comment: In that regard Less variables actually never store a *result* of the expressions, what they always store is the expression itself (because of the lazy evaluation, see example at [#16](https://github.com/less/less-meta/issues/16#issuecomment-292227052) and comments above it).